# Unsupported operand types: string / int in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, syntax-error

I have a Laravel booking clinic system. When I run the code I received this error.

"Unsupported operand types: string / int"

Here is my code.

```
<li><img class="icons" src="{{asset('public/assets/img/icons/cash.png')}}">{{__('AED')}} @if(@$list->discount !=0){{ round($list->dr_fees - ($list->dr_fees * ($list->discount / 100))) }} @else {{@$list->dr_fees}} @endif{{__('Consultation')}}  </li>
```

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Check you `$list->discount` variable. Looks like you are passing it as a string value.

Try casting it as `(int) $list->discount`.